# Display output of MySQL query on button badge

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php mysql & have this query where i want to display the output of mysql query on button badge. I have tried the following code 
Kindly help .

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysqli_select_db($con,"sales");
$sth = mysqli_query($con,"select sum(sal) as Salary from `sales` ");
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sth);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con,$result);     
echo $row;
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary <span class="badge"><?php echo $row; ?></span></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're echo-ing the wrong thing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo ''.$row['Salary'].''; ?>
```

As long as you have verified the settings and the query is correct the above line should output what you are looking for.

EDIT

```
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysqli_select_db($con,"sales");
$sth = "select sum(sal) as Salary from `sales` ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sth);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Try That

Comment: Nope. Not getting the desired o/p.

Comment: That means you have issues with your query. Not seeing the say your database is set up I can not comment on that

Comment: When i run the query on MySQL console i get the right output. I need to display the same on the button bade

Comment: what do you get when you do print_r($row);

Comment: Error 1 : 
( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given  on line 5

Comment: Error 2 : ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given on line 6

Comment: Ok 2 things, first remove the $con from the mysqli_fetch_assco and the second thing is why are you running mysqli_query twice?

Comment: Thank You ! Got the desired O/p

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if the problem is solved. Thanks!